# Loop through nested object in angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, ngfor

I want to loop through the the nested object.

```
"movieRating": {
"rate": [{ 
    "rating9": 9,
    "count9": 158
}, {
    "rating8": 8,
    "count8": 101
}, {
    "rating7": 7,
    "count7": 32
}, {
    "rating6": 6,
    "count6": 48
}, {
    "rating5": 5,
    "count5": 125
}],
"totalCount": 456}
```

This is my HTML file

```
<div *ngFor="let movie of movies" class="container">
    <table   class="table">
        <tbody>
            <tr >
                <th><img src="#"></th>
                <td >{{movie.movieRating.rating9}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

If I try `{{movie.movieRating.rating9}}` this is not working. 
But `{{movie.movieRating.totalCount}}` works.
Is there a way to get `rating9` and `count9`.

Comment: Do yo want only 9 or others as well?

Comment: Currently I am testing it only for count9 and rating9.

Answer (score 3):

`Rating9` is in position 0 of the rate array, so to access it you can use `{{movie.movieRating.rate[0].rating9}}`.

```html
<div *ngFor="let movie of movies" class="container">
    <table   class="table">
        <tbody>
            <tr >
                <th><img src="#"></th>
                <td >{{movie.movieRating.rate[0].rating9}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`movieRating` has a property called `rate`, which is a list of `ratings`. So, it would be like `movie.movieRating.rate[0].rating9`.

But the HTML part what you have posted in this question will give only one row, that is `rating9`'s row, then it's no use of looping. So generalise your `rate` object like below:

```
"rate": {
    "rating": 9,
    "count": 158
}
```

So It would be very easy to loop also in the future.. like below:

```html
<div *ngFor="let rating of movies.movieRating.rate" class="container">
    <table   class="table">
        <tbody>
            <tr >
                <th><img src="#"></th>
                <td >{{rating}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When accessing nested object array elements, first you have to loop through the main array in your case its "movies". Then you have to loop through the nested array called "rate" inside the movie object then you can access the rate values as follows.

Your nested array.

```
movies:[{
 "movieRating": {
   "rate": [{ 
     "rating9": 9,
     "count9": 158
    }, {
     "rating8": 8,
     "count8": 101
    }, {
     "rating7": 7,
     "count7": 32
    }, {
     "rating6": 6,
     "count6": 48
    }, {
     "rating5": 5,
     "count5": 125
    }],
   "totalCount": 456}
}]
```

Modified html code

```
<div *ngFor="let movie of movies" class="container">
    <table   class="table">
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let rate of movie.movieRating.rate" >
                <th><img src="#"></th>
                <td >{{movie.movieRating.rating9}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```